# Right click in finder - open folder in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext, automator, finder

I'd like to be able to right click a folder in finder then choose an option on that menu to open it directly in sublime, including its full contents tree.  This saves me the repetitive task of opening a terminal, manually navigating to the correct directory, then typing `subl .`

I followed the [instructions here](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2012/06/18/right-click-open-with-sublime-text-2) (2012) but it doesn't seem to work for me on the current version of OS X.

Comment: A simple way to do this is drag the folder onto the sublime icon in the doc, but I'm curious how to get automator to do it too.

Comment: If using github desktop, a related convenence is to right click on name of a repo in the sidebar - 'open in terminal' is built in. Glorious.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the method here:
https://gist.github.com/vincentmac/6703537
and it worked for me.

I had to include willcharlton's correction as well:

`/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n "$@"`

Also `-n` allows you to open it in a new sublime window, `-a` allows you to add to existing sublime window.